# Are there any good instructional chess videos in German with captions?

Tags: learning

I would like to watch chess videos, and improve my German at the same time, and youtube has a a few videos with captions, but I can't find any videos that are chess-related AND in German AND with Captions.

Comment: I'm not sure about captions, but many of the titles by Mueller from ChessBase have both English and German for the same learning material on one disc.

Comment: I had found videos included in the Fritz 13 to be in German. But the videos doesn't seem to have captions.

Comment: Some of Daniel King's ChessBase DVDs are dual-language as well.

Answer (score 3):

I have found this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PHl0kP2LpuU)(This Guy has a quite lot videos). It is in German, it is about Chess and you can turn the Captions on, but I think they were generated from a computer. Since I as a German guy can say, its not really, what he is actually saying, but it might help you.